# assigning new value to an object in object array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects

object will be in below format

```
var newUserDetail={"Age":"21","name":"Vicky","UserId":"198303"};
```

Now I am trying to compare UserId and replace the values

```
//usersList contains array of newUserDetail kind of objects

jQuery(usersList).each(function(){
if(this.UserId==newUserDetail.UserId){
this=newUserDetail;
}
});
```

But it throws an error

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: sorry! check the edited question

Comment: i think it's probably because "this" inside the if condition, and why this=newUserDetail; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the array entry:

```
jQuery(usersList).each(function (i) {
    if (this.UserId == newUserDetail.UserId) {
        usersList[i] = newUserDetail;
        return false; //if you want to break the loop
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newUserDetail = {
    "Age": "21",
    "name": "Vicky",
    "UserId": "198303"
  };

  var tm = {
    "Age": "21",
    "name": "Vicky",
    "UserId": "198303"
  };
  $.each(newUserDetail, function(k, i) {
    if (i == tm.UserId) {
      alert("User ID match");
    }


  })



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```